# Installing Skype on 12.10 64 bit causes errors

Tags: 12.10, 64-bit, package-management, skype

I have installed **Ubuntu 12.10 64bit (clean install)** and updated it.

After that i tried to install `skype`, and i get error that `skype` depends `skype-bin`, but it could not install it, and that there are some broken packages!?

In Ubuntu software center there is no `skype`. And when I try to download it from skype website it installs it via software center and it displays the error that it is not supported because it's `i386`...

So, how this is possible on clean install of Ubuntu 64bit?
And how to fix it?
And will someone fix it in next update?

Thanks in advance,
Predrag

Comment: If you have tried it with 64-bit-package, then remove it again,
and try it with 32-bit-package of skype. Don't know if 64-bit-package-feature is meanwhile resolved, but
it was similiar problem with earlier package of google-earth
and with debian ( there 64-bit-package did not work too - but
32-bit-package was running fine ).

Comment: @dschinn1001: what Predrag is saying is that there's no 64-bit package for Skype. He's running Ubuntu 64-bit. Now I understand why Ubuntu recommends the 32-bit OS...

Answer (score 1):

This is more of a comment than an answer (because it doesn't provide a solution, since there isn't one at the time) but: there is no functional 64-bit .deb Skype package for Ubuntu 12.10 64-bit. Source: [Skype forums](http://community.skype.com/t5/Linux/skype-for-the-new-ubuntu-12-10/td-p/1135376).

The package http://download.skype.com/linux/skype-ubuntu_4.0.0.7-1_amd64.deb is "fake" (source: http://www.mindwerks.net/2012/06/skype-4-0-on-ubuntu-precise-12-04-64-bit-2/). Trying to install it will ultimately fail with `E: Package 'ia32-libs-multiarch' has no installation candidate`

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Skype is outdated and incorrect - the Canonical partner repo doesn't list Skype.

Summary: you're [SOL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shit_Out_of_Luck)

Answer (score -2):

Why don't you try removing it first.

> sudo apt-get autoremove skype

Try reinstalling it.

> sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install skype

What do you get?

EDIT

Try doing

> sudo apt-get install skype-bin

before doing the earlier part.

Comment: 'Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 skype : Depends: skype-bin but it is not installable
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages'

Comment: Same error with `skype-bin` not being installable.