# How can I install ubuntu 32 bit arquitechture when I am currently running a 64 bit windiws 7?

Tags: skype

When I downloaded ubuntu from the ubuntu page, it asked me my architechture of preference; I obviously chose x64-bit. I have been trying to install skype, but it is impossible on the 64 bit version of ubuntu 12.04, so I tried to download the 32 bit version of ubuntu instead. Every time I choose 32 bits, when installing, it automatically installs the 64 bit version. This is because I am currently running a 64 bit version of windows, and I don't know what to do for it not to acknowledge that it's a 64 bit system. Can someone please tell me how to either install ubuntu 32 bits or skype on a 64 bit ubuntu 12.04?
Thanks.

Comment: Here you go: [Install Skype](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Skype#Installing_Skype). Who told you it's  not possible to install a 32bit program on a 64bit OS?

Comment: It sounds like you're using Wubi. That defaults to 64bits if supported (use `--32bit` to override). Also there's a multiarch bug in the Wubi 64bit preinstalled image. `sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386` to fix

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it matters what architecture you have on Windows 64 or 32 bit all that means is that the 64 bit will use more cores of your processor meaning faster computing as for 32 bit will run slower.

Apparently others are simply having problems with the 64bit skype install read this.

[Installing Skype on 12.10 64 bit causes errors](https://askubuntu.com/questions/218085/installing-skype-on-12-10-64-bit-causes-errors)

Hope this helps, but good luck.  This is all I could really find on the skype issue, I think it's an issue with skype not ubuntu.  I wouldn't waste time re-installing your system though.  Cheers!

Comment: I think bcbc's comment is a good answer though.  I'd try that.